# How can I run some jQuery against a table to change padding depending on column value?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and I need to make it so the padding in the second column of my table depends on the number in the first column.

```
<tr>
   <td id="refKey_1" style="text-align:center;" class=" sorting_1">1.0.0</td>
   <td id="Title_1">
      <input type="text" value="x" size="100" name="item.Title" id="item_Title_1">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="refKey_2" style="text-align:center;" class=" sorting_1">1.2.0</td>
  <td id="Title_2">
      <input type="text" value="xx" size="100" name="item.Title" id="item_Title_2">
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td id="refKey_3" style="text-align:center;" class=" sorting_1">1.3.4</td>
   <td id="Title_3">
      <input type="text" value="xxx" size="100" name="item.Title" id="item_Title_3">
   </td>
</tr>
```

What I need is for the second column to have a left padding of 0, 10px or 20px depending if the first column id ends in 0.0, .0 or a non zero.

Is there a way I can do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by `id` you mean the cell's text, right? Just some regex matching to do this.

```
$('tr').each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find('td'),
        text = tds.filter('[id^="refKey_"]').text(),
        tdToPad = tds.filter('[id^="Title_"]'),
        pad;
    if (/0\.0$/.test(text))
        pad=0;
    else if (/\.0$/.test(text))
        pad=10;
    else
        pad=20;
    tdToPad.css('paddingLeft', pad);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cynSk/4/)

**edit:** You may also use a common class instead of these ID selectors, which would be a more standard approach. Also, you can add the table's ID to the first selector: `$('#tableID tr')` in case you have multiple tables in your page.

Comment: You don't have to use 'each.' JQ handles multiple elements in a selection until you want to do unique things to each one.

Comment: @ErikReppen I'm handling each `tr` with a function callback. This is a perfect working solution as per live demo, now if you have a better solution I'm listening.

Comment: This looks very good. Is there a way that you could make it work so that it keyed on the td with and id of refKey_XX  and then padded the td with an id of Title_XXX  thanks so much

Comment: @Gemma - Working from ids is messy for this sort of thing. If you are trying to allow for changes to the markup where the number of columns might change I'd give the columns to be updated a common class.

Comment: No problem Erik. `:)` @Gemma I'm not sure what you're asking, all IDs end in `_1` `_2` `_3`. Do you want the padding depending on how many digits the ID has? As nnnnnn this is really messy but I can do that if you provide an example output of what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tableThatICareAbout').find('tr > td').eq(1)
.css('padding-left',

$('#tableThatICareAbout').find('tr > td').eq(0)[0].id.split('_')[1]

);
```

I would expect this to work but it's a horrible, terrible way to deal with this problem whatever the core problem is.

Comment: Would you mind indenting the code a little? This doesn't seem to work for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cynSk/3/)

Comment: That code will only update the first row. You can do something similar using the [`:nth-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)` but you need to use the callback syntax of `.css()`.

Comment: What, are you saying my gin-soaked solutions aren't as practical as your practical solutions?

Comment: +1 for the comment. `:P` Yes, let me grab some vodka before I continue working with table cells in jQuery.